# Array access results in a null pointer dereference

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, null

I have the following for each loop which compares several guids with each other.

```
stringc flanking_id = *flanking_it;

if (abzug) {
    if (AppFrame::isValidPointer(&flanking_id)) {
        if (AppFrame::isValidPointer(&abzug->guid)) {
            if (flanking_id.size() > 0 && abzug->guid.size() > 0) {
                if (flanking_id.size() >= abzug->guid.size()) {
                    if (flanking_id.equalsn(abzug->guid, abzug->guid.size())) {
                        return bauteil;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

abzug-guid is an core::stringw which is an Irrlicht-Engine datatype.

isValidPointer calls a method which is containing the following two lines

```
BOOL result = somePointer != 0 && somePointer != NULL && somePointer != nullptr && somePointer != nil;

return result;
```

So it shouldn't be possible, that one of my guids is broken. But Xcode says there is a possible null pointer dereference in this line.

```
if (flanking_id.equalsn(abzug->guid, abzug->guid.size())) {
```

This is the warning...

```
Array access (via field 'array') results in a null pointer dereference (within a call to 'equalsn')
```

How to solve this hint?

EDIT: equalsn() from irrString.h by Irrlicht-Engine

```
bool equalsn(const string<T,TAlloc>& other, u32 n) const
{
    u32 i;
    for(i=0; i < n && array[i] && other[i]; ++i)
        if (array[i] != other[i])
            return false;

    // if one (or both) of the strings was smaller then they
    // are only equal if they have the same length
    return (i == n) || (used == other.used);
}
```

Comment: The result of applying the address-of operator (`&`)  can never be a null pointer.  (And all the comparisons in `isValidPointer` are equivalent.)

Comment: `isValidPointer` doesn't tell you whether it's valid, just that it's not null (using three equivalant tests) and not equal to whatever `nil` is. It could be uninitialised, or pointing to the remnants of a destroyed object, or otherwise corrupted, and still pass those tests.

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten to mention the line where the hint appears.

Comment: The "within a call to 'equalsn'" means that the problem is inside that function of the `stringc` class. What do that function and `stringc`'s copy constructor look like?

Comment: @molbdnilo, added this to the question :)

Comment: do you know if `flanking_it` is valid?  If `equalsn()` is throwing the error and it is a library function then more than likely something is wrong with `flanking_it`.

Comment: if i check the 'validity' of flanking_it before equalsn the analyst-hint in xcode appears always......

Comment: If `flanking_id.size() > abzug->guid.size()` then `array[i]` will be out of range in `equalsn()`.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, i've editi the code above... it's always presenting the null dereference analysis hint...

Comment: Oh by the way, that's a disturbing view!!! Have you read Torvalds message about 3 levels of indentation? You went way to far to contradict him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bvo7hQ)

```
int * p1 = 0;
int p2 = *p1;
cout << "&p2 != 0: " << (&p2 != 0) << endl;
cout << "*p1 = 1 : " << flush;
*p1 = 1;
cout << "ok" << endl;
```

Output:

```
Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 3096 signal:11

&p2 != 0: 1
*p1 = 1 :
```

So, the check for valid pointer after the last one was dereferenced is useless. It should be

```
if (abzug) {
    if (AppFrame::isValidPointer(flanking_it)) {
        stringc flanking_id = *flanking_it;
        //...
```

Concerning warning, I'm not sure what Xcode dislikes, but I suspect this lines

```
for(i=0; i < n && array[i] && other[i]; ++i)  // line 1
    if (array[i] != other[i])                 // line 2
```

There is should be check in `line 1` that index `i` is less then size of `array`. In case of `n` greater than source string length there will be error.

BTW, instead of 7 enclosed `if-statements` you can use

```
if (!abzug ||
    !AppFrame::isValidPointer(&flanking_id) ||
    !AppFrame::isValidPointer(&abzug->guid) ||
    ... {
    return ...;
}
if (flanking_id.equalsn(abzug->guid, abzug->guid.size())) {
    return bauteil;
}
```

Or if a `return` statement can not be used then

```
do {
    if (!abzug ||
        !AppFrame::isValidPointer(&flanking_id) ||
        !AppFrame::isValidPointer(&abzug->guid) ||
        ... {
        break;
    }
    if (flanking_id.equalsn(abzug->guid, abzug->guid.size())) {
        return bauteil;
    }
} while (0);
```

Comment: Thanks for these details! :) This works now without memory hints... :)

Comment: You could use a `goto` instead of a `do while` + `break`... – for breaking out of an `if` statement...